# Label won't stay vertical center, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with this label, it doesn't seem to want to stay vertically centered, it's always at the top, if anyone can help that would be great, thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/tu7moprn/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="innertext">Text Test Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div><span class="label label-default pull-right">New</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
h4 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
hr {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.innertext {
    display:inline-block;
    width:90%
}
```

Comment: What do you want to center vertically, the whole container?

Comment: @caeth the label that says "new"

Comment: but you need new always at the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the class `pull-right` from the label and then add this proeprties:

```
.label {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
.innertext {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tu7moprn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always override by adding `position: absolute;`, `top: 50%;` and `margin-top: -x;` (mind the minus), where x is a half of the height of your label. It will center you label vertically. Don't forget to set `position: relative;` to parent of that `span` element. It will always stay on the middle of parent div.

If this is what you want. Otherwise provide more details.

Here is a working fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r0gsewtd/